# JavaFX codesign issues in Mac bundle

Tags: javafx, codesign

I'm building a javaFX bundle for Mac and am adding an Uninstaller.app to the bundle.
As prt of  the code is signed and I insert Uninstaller folder as a fileset into the  (among other files).
But, when code is building I always get an error when trying to codesign "Application Stub" under Uninstaller.app->Contents->MacOS.
This is the message I get:

> Running [codesign, -s, Developer ID Application: xxx, --prefix, test.com.xxx.yyy., -vvvv, /var/folders/02/6nmx541x4rq4f6mz3n9__px40000gn/T/fxbundler11458933583542045410/images/image-17325795275411389984/xxx-TEST.app/Contents/Java/Uninstaller.app/Contents/MacOS/Application Stub]
>   /var/folders/02/6nmx541x4rq4f6mz3n9__px40000gn/T/fxbundler11458933583542045410/images/image-17325795275411389984/xxx-TEST.app/Contents/Java/Uninstaller.app/Contents/MacOS/Application Stub: **code object is not signed at all
>   In subcomponent:** /private/var/folders/02/6nmx541x4rq4f6mz3n9__px40000gn/T/fxbundler11458933583542045410/images/image-17325795275411389984/xxx-TEST.app/Contents/Java/Uninstaller.app/Contents/document.wflow

Where document.wflow is an Automator file one folder above Application Stub file.

[image]

I'm loosing my hair in here and am trying to solve it for the last 2 weeks.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you problem be related to non-ASCII symbol in application name like [here](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-osx-sign/issues/155#issuecomment-342870340)?

Comment: Nope. I have no non-ascii chars in my app name or similar.